# I am receiving a "Frame Not in Module" error while running this program in c

Tags: c, module

Hi wrote this to be able to save a string with an infinite size
but after running it VS 2019 although the out put is correct but instead of ending the program it shows a page with a "frame not in module" as a header and sort of freezed

```
#pragma warning(disable : 6385)

#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys\timeb.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <wchar.h>


main() {
    int maxline = 2;
    int a = 0;
    char c; char line[3]; int i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        i++;
        
        line[a++] = c;
        
        if (i == maxline) {
            line[maxline+=4];
        } 
        
        
}
    line[++a] = '/0';


    while (--a > 0) printf("%c", line[i-a]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do the variable `a` never go out of bounds of the array `line` (i.e. is the condition `a < 3` always true)? What happens when you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: On that issue (out of bounds) the statement `line[maxline+=4];` is ***guaranteed*** to go out of bounds. And does nothing else.

Comment: Lastly note that the [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function return an **`int`**. This is very important for that `EOF` comparison.

Comment: "to be able to save a string with an infinite size" Please explain how this code will save strings of infinite size in a buffer that can hold 3 characters. It makes no sense to me...

Comment: And what is the purpose of this `line[maxline+=4]` ?

Comment: And why print the string like this `while (--a > 0) printf("%c", line[i-a]);` ? Seems to me you could simply do `printf("%s", line);`

Comment: `line[maxline+=4];` Is this supposed to redefine the array with a new size? That cannot work.

Comment: `line[++a] = '/0';` This causes a gap between read characters and the nul terminator as the previous element was `line[a++]=c;` which already incremented `a`.

Comment: Thank you all ,I wanted to change the array size as program runs. I did a little bit of searching and couldn't find a routine , so I started trying different approaches and finally this worked I had problems whit printing the array as string although I add the last null. but now at the end after returning the out put correctly instead of exiting it freezes and directs me to a page where it says frame not in module

Comment: again thank you all for your responses I moved this macro too the actual source file and the error disappeared by it self, :):):)

Comment: it didn't make sense I knew c/c++ shouldn't do an array index of bound check